# How does one split up a non-explicitly given string into two or more lines?

Tags: python, word-wrap

I'm currently working with a Python bot that outputs an image with text, but I've found out that oftentimes the text is too long to be presented. Thus, I've decided to split up the string into two lines so it can fit into my image. I am utilizing Pillow 5.1 for image manipulaton.

I am a neophyte to Python programming, and I've tried to search how to split up a Python string into two or more lines. Unfortunately, all of the results seem to only deal with strings explictly given(i.e 'string').

```
print("Ababoubian wisdom!")
ababou2 = ababou() #returns a string, how to split into two lines?
if("Ababou" in ababou2):
    ababou2 = ababou()
font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", 14)
img = Image.new('RGB', (300, 200), color = (random.randint(0, 255),random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((0, 0), ababou2, font=font) #draws text
```

[image: Actual results]

Expected results: The text should wrap around to the next line.

Comment: What's the difference between "explicitly given" and "non-explicitly given"? If you're splitting a string, there _must_ be a string to split, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html

Comment: @ForceBru I think I meant to say a string where you can't see its explicit form. Sorry for being ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure a text wrapper could help in your case since you need to draw each line separately.

Seems like you should calculate the maximum length of chars in a single line, then do:

```
ababou2 = ababou() # Whats the point of assigning the same value twice? 
                   # does ababou() returns a different value each time?
if "Ababou" in ababou2:
    ababou2 = ababou()

res_text = list()
ababou2 = ababou2.split(' ') # Splits the string by space\ ' ', to a list of strings 
curr_txt = ''
for word in ababou2:
    if len(curr_txt) < MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE: # This you need to figure out
        curr_txt += ' '  + word
    else:
        res_text.append(curr_txt)
        curr_txt = word

font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", 14)
img = Image.new('RGB', (300, 200), color = (random.randint(0, 255),random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
y = 0
for line in res_text:
    d.text((0, y), line, font=font) #draws text
    y += SINGLE_ROW_SPACE # Figure out what is the distance between two rows.
```

Comment: When you are printing out lines in your last for loop, shouldn't it be "d.text((0,y), line, font=font), as ababou2 is a list?

Comment: Good catch, should be line since we're iterating over the line of res_text!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are dealing with fonts, you will want to be aware of the [`getsize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize) method. This will help you figure out how to split the text.

Suppose you have a string:

```
def get_a_string():
    return "here is some string"

text = get_a_string()
```

Now, you also have an image which has a width and height:

```
bgcolor = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
img = Image.new('RGB', (300, 200), color=bgcolor)

# Read the size tuple, unpack into height, width
img_height, img_width = img.size
```

If the text is too long, you should shorten it:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", 14)

text_height, text_width = font.getsize(text)

if text_width > (0.95 * img_width):
    # Not enough room. Break the text
    lines = split_by_words()
```

How can you shorten it? First, try using word boundaries:

```
def split_by_words(text):
    text = text.rstrip() # Strip trailing whitespace

    words = text.split()
    lines = []

    while words:
        # I use None instead of '' to allow for leading spaces
        line = None

        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            new_line = word if line is None else line + ' ' + word
            (h, w) = font.getsize(new_line)

            if w > img_width:
                # New line won't fit? Break, keeping old line value.
                break
            else:
                # Still fits? Save it!
                line = new_line

        if i == 0:
            # First word was too long. Try character-by-character
            lines.extend(split_by_character(words[0]))
            # TODO: You might want to put lines[-1] into words[0] to join long first word
            # remainder with short second word.
            words = words[1:]
        else:
            lines.append(line)
            words = words[i:]

    return lines
```

This is going to call `getsize` a bunch of times, which might be expensive. (Or not: if you're generating memes from cat pics it probably doesn't cost much since the text is short. If you're writing a word processor, beware!)

An alternative would be to compute the size of the original text, then assume all characters are the same width and make a guess about where the split should be based on the ratio of image size to text size:

```
th, tw = font.getsize(text)
ih, iw = img.size

ratio = iw / tw  # 300 / 622, say
split_pos = int(len(text) * ratio)  # 0.51 * text len, about halfway along

line1 = text[:split_pos]

if font.getsize(line1) > iw:
    while True:
        split_pos -= 1
        line1 = line1[:-1]
        if font.getsize(line1) <= iw:
            break
else: # too short
    while True:
        line1 += text[split_pos]
        if font.getsize(line1) > iw:
            line1 = line1[:-1]
            break
        split_pos += 1
```

Note that this is character-based, rather than word-based, so it kind of sucks. And since most fonts are proportional, the ratio is probably wrong. You might be able to tune it using some heuristics, including a built-in set of width assumptions. (just compute the width of all letters one time, store them in a table, and assume all fonts use that width - still wrong, but usually a better approximation than the ratio method, and faster!)

Comment: I'll take a look at your answer, but in the meantime thanks for being comprehensive and through,